# md-error in angular-material2 how to limit it to only one error when validation fails

Tags: angular, angular-material2

in angular material 2 for input validation they say:

> If an input element can have more than one error state, it is up to the consumer to toggle which messages should be displayed. This can be done with CSS, ngIf or ngSwitch.

but if I have say the following

```
  <md-input-container class="full-width">
  <input type="Email" mdInput [formControl]="formControls.emailFormControl" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="formData.email"
    required>
  <md-error *ngIf="formControls.emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Email is <strong>required</strong>
  </md-error>
  <md-error *ngIf="formControls.emailFormControl.hasError('email')">
    Email is <strong>invalid</strong>
  </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

how without having to have multiple && statements do I limit it to one error if both validations fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the valid attribute:

```
<md-error *ngIf="!formControls.emailFormControl.valid">
  Email is <strong>invalid</strong> or <strong>missing</strong>
</md-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also share a single `md-error` and just alter the error string

```
<md-error>
  Email is <strong>getErrorMessageType()</strong>
</md-error>


getErrorMessageType(): string {
  if (formControls.emailFormControl.hasError('required') {
    return 'required';
  } else {
    return 'invalid';
  }
}
```